# Ошибка при запуске программы на mac os

Tags: macos, mac, macbook

Когда пытаюсь запустить программу .app на macos Ventora 13.5 появляется ошибка: The installation cannot continue as the installer file may be damaged. Download the installer file again.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже пробовал комманду: sudo spctl --master-disable не помогает. при запуска программы из папки macos в содержимом пакета таже ошибка а в консоле

Exit Code: 1

Saving session...

...copying shared history...

...saving history...truncating history files...

...completed.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите что делать?